# Error after woocommerce update from 2.6 to 3.5

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_breadcrumb() on string in /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/assets/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php:321 Stack trace: #0 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WC_Structured_Data->generate_breadcrumblist_data('') #1 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/assets/themes/Elfai/woocommerce.php(6): do_action('woocommerce_bre...') #4 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include('/home/elaieu/do...') #5 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/elaieu/do...') #6 /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/elaieu/do...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/elaieu/domains/elfai.lt/public_html/assets/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php on line 321

Answer (score 0):

That can be because of plugin conflict,  can you deactivate all your plugins and try to enable one by one to find out which plugin is causing the problem. 
Also, check your PHP version (recommended is 7.2).

Thanks !!!